# Plymouth messed up

Tags: boot, plymouth

I used Plymouth manager, trying to the usual thing (changing the boot splash). It did this, but to the wrong one - so I tried to change it back. 
This apparently failed and I started to get an error like `Boot Splash failed to load - Too many levels of symbolic links`. 
It would then display all of the drivers loading (after a small pause) and then go to the login screen. After some updates I ran about a month ago it went totally black and nothing shows, not even the error. It still loads the login screen and works fine, but nothing displays during boot-up.

I really kind of liked the Ubuntu splash and want it back. Any help is accepted thankfully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiped and installed Ubuntu 13.04. Everything is fine and dandy now. Loving Ubuntu 13.04!